# How to update records of one table with the values of another one (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `t1` with columns `account_id` and `user_id`, and another table `users` with columns `id` and `account_id`. I want to populate `t1.account_id` with the values of `users.account_id`.

For instance having

```
t1
user_id account_id
1       NULL
2       NULL
```

and

```
users
id account_id
1  10
2  11
```

I would like to populate `t1.account_id` with these values:

```
t1
user_id account_id
1       10
2       11
```

I've seen [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36664/59825) for MySQL but can't have it working with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Did you try another answer to that same question? http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21154/10361 should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[update documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

```
UPDATE t1 AS a SET
  account_id = b.account_id
FROM users b
WHERE a.user_id = b.id;
```

The key is that you need to make sure you have a link between the table you're updating (aliased as "a" in my example) and the table you're using .. which is done via the WHERE clause... `a.user_id = b.id`